# Registering controller Issue Angular 1.6.4

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, angular-controller

I am using Angular 1.6.4 and I can't seem to get the HeaderController to work. This HeaderController will display the navigation bar. Am I not calling it correctly in the HTML? My other components work because I call it using the route templates. Any help or suggestion would be great!

Here is the error message:

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name
>   'headerController' is not registered.

Here is my HeaderComponent.js

```js
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.component('headerController', {
        templateUrl: 'Content/app/components/layout/Header.html',
        controller: HeaderController
    })

    function HeaderController() {

    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling my controller in the body element:

```html
<div ng-controller="headerController"></div>
```

Comment: you seem to be mixing concerns here.  you created a **component** called `headerController`, which itself defined a **controller** called `HeaderController`.  you wouldn't use `ng-controller` to invoke the component, nor would you need `ng-controller` to invoke `HeaderController`, since it is implicitly invoked when the component is initialized.

Comment: @Claies I see. How would I get the template of the component to display on the HTML?

Comment: To consume this component, use it's normalized HTML element, i.e. `<header-controller></header-controller>`.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: @Claies Awesome that worked! Thanks